# ionic splashscreen gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on older android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

After I package build my release using the Ionic Pro service, download it, and install it on a Android 4.4.2 device, I get an alert right over the splashscreen titled: "Application Error", with the following error:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhjost:8080/)
```

After a while the splashscreen dissapears and a white page says: "*Webpage not available*:"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8blbM.png)

It runs fine on another device, running Android 8.0.0.

What could cause this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your cordova-plugin-webview to 1.2.1, because version 2.x.x using http:// protocol instead of file://

https://ionic.zone/debug/ionic-and-android-4

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people will suggest you to add to your config.xml the following line

```
  <allow-intent href="http://localhost:<YOUR_PORT_HERE>/*" />
```

You already have this , so the above line is useless

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Some users will suggest you to downgrade the **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview** plugin to to 2.1.2 version, for some users work for others not.

What i suggest you to do in your **package.json** file, add this to your 
**cordova-plugin-ionic-webview**

**from:**

```
 "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
```

**to:**

```
 "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
```